# User Defined Function SQL Error

Tags: sql-server, view, user-defined-functions

I have written this function but it does not return the address table information.

```
CREATE FUNCTION returnInfo()
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT
SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID, 
FirstName,
LastName,
Phone
FROM SalesLT.Customer
RIGHT JOIN SalesLT.Address 
ON SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID = SalesLT.Address.AddressID;
```

CustomerID and AddressID are both the Primary keys for the tables, and they do not share a foreign key. Any ideas on how to join the Address table into what I have selected?

Comment: You cannot create a user-defined function inside a view ..... check [the official documentation on `CREATE VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - it's basically a `SELECT` only (possibly with JOINs and WHERE) - but you most definitely cannot create other DB objects inside a view definition

Comment: If SalesLT.Customer and SalesLT.Address tables don't share a foreign key then that gives me a suspicion that you have somewhere a table in SalesLT that has foreign keys to both those tables.  Maybe something like SalesLT.CustomerAddress.  But it seems that your query only uses fields from Customer. Unless you need the Address that join seems unneeded.

Comment: Yes, SalesLT.CustomerAddress does contain two foreign keys. Should I join CustomerAddress on both the foreign keys?

Comment: CustomerAddress should join to Customer and address, they should not join directly to each other. Note this means one customer can have two+ addresses, or one address can have multiple customers.

Comment: @Javascripttech you have defaced your own question by editing it the way you did. I rolled back your destructive edit. Feel free to delete this question, but don't destroy question content.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you feel the need to create a function inside a view... what are you trying to accomplish??

A `VIEW` in SQL Server is basically just a stored `SELECT` - possibly with JOINs and WHERE clauses - but nothing more. And that's more or less exactly what your "nested" UDF is doing....

From what you've posted, you would define that view something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Customer]
AS 
    SELECT
        CustomerID, 
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Phone
    FROM 
        SalesLT.Customer;
GO
```

There's absolutely no need and no benefit in creating any user-defined function here......